# How is the schedule produced in NS2?

Tags: ns2

Reposting this from EE since folk there don't seem to know the answer.

I am interested in seeing how the NS2 schedule of events is created based on the TCL script. Is there an intermediate file I could look at? Or perhaps there is a book or chapter in a book that talks about it?

I have the NS2 code, but I'm not sure where to look.

Edit: Here is a link to NS2: http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/ . It is a discrete event wireless simulator. To run a simulation, one supplies a script (written in TCL), which describes the network topology, node-to-node connections and so on. When the simulation is run, a schedule of events (because this is discrete time events sim) is created.

I want to know how this schedule is created and what it looks like. For example, if I have a network of 1000 nodes, all communicating in response to an already received packet, how does it schedule the responses? Are those done at runtime?

Thanks (PS. Sorry if this is in the wrong place)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by scheduling the responses? NS2 allows you to track all the events in the network by using a trace-all command (or something similar) in your script. Check ns2 Trace Format online to understand better how this works and how the events are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

there are many types of ns2 schedulers( real-time, heap,calendar..)
the default scheduled is the "calendar scheduler"
it is automatically called when you create new simulator instance in tcl file.

in this tcl file you specify some event and the time of its occurance

the events may be a sending or receiving packet or  creating a node or ... 
these events may also call many other event,  and the mission of scheduler is to arrange these events in the time series

please take a look at ns-allin_one-2.35/common/scheduler.cc
https://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/doc/node32.html

very nice explination here

https://www.slideshare.net/TBear76/ns2event-scheduler

regards